# React Router won't work in production if a main component return other components

Tags: reactjs, react-router

First, everything is working great during tests, but not when I build the project.

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
      <Router>
      <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Installation />} />
      <Route path="/admin" element={<Admin />} />
      </Routes>
      </Router>

  );
}
```

The `<Installation />` component renders perfectly, the problem is with `<Admin />`. This is what the component returns:

```
return(
    <div>   
    <TopBar name={site.name}/>
    <LeftBar lang={site.lang}/> 
    </div>  
    );
```

Both TopBar and LeftBar are inside the same file as Admin. When I access localhost/admin, it shows a blank page. But if I remove TopBar and LeftBar from Admin and add a simple text, it renders normally.

So I concluded that, React Router has a problem with components that return other components, at least in production.

Update: It's not a problem with the Admin component returning other components. The problem is with useSelector that gets the initial state for site name and language, and passes it to TopBar and LeftBar. If I remove the props references, it works.

Comment: If there is a blank page, there might be a runtime error. Did you check the console?

Comment: React Router does not have a problem with components that return other components

Comment: I don't see any overt issues with the code snippets you've shared. The problem is likely elsewhere. As previously asked, are there any errors/warnings in the console? What debugging steps have you taken to diagnose this issue? Do you need to provide a more complete/comprehensive code example in order to have a reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DrewReese No console erros, that's why I was blind. But I found out what the problem is, but I still don't know how to solve it. The problem is with the state passed as prop. The Admin component uses useSelector from Redux to get the initial state for site name and language, and it passes it to TobBar and LeftBar. If I remove the props references, it renders. I don't know what's going on, because it works with npm start.

Comment: Do you mind editing your question to include these new details and relevant code? Also, if possible, do you think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't easy to find the cause of this because React won't tell you exactly where the problem is. It was a combination of wrong state property in one component and not properly accessing a property in another.

For some reason, this was working with npm start:

```
const site = useSelector((state) => state.settings);
<TopBar name={site.sitename} />

function TopBar (siteName) {
return(
<div>
<h6>{siteName}</h6>
</div>
);
}
```

I had to change it to:

```
function TopBar (prop) {
return(
<div>
<h6>{prop.name}</h6>
</div>
);
}
```

Also, there was a component receiving a wrong property from a reducer. I fixed that, and now everything works.